# How to set Dropdownlist value in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

i have a method to populate the dropdownlist in asp.net using C#

```
public void get_country_box_populated(ref System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList dropDown, bool add_initial_text)
{
    dropDown.Items.Clear();
    //dropDown.Items.Add(0,"Select Any Country");
    var context = new db_vmartEntities();
    var query = from c in context.tbl_countary
                where c.status == true
                select new { c.countary_id, c.countary_name };

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    if (add_initial_text)
    {
        dictionary.Add(0, "Select Any Country");
    }
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        dictionary.Add(item.countary_id, item.countary_name);
    }
    dropDown.DataTextField = "Value";
    dropDown.DataValueField = "Key";
    dropDown.DataSource = dictionary;  //Dictionary<int, string>
    dropDown.DataBind();
}
```

now i need to select a default value on edit page something like this.

```
store_registration my_store = str.get_store_by_id(Session["user"].ToString(), sid);
c.get_country_box_populated(ref countary_box,false);
countary_box.Text = countary_box.Items.FindByValue(my_store.countary).ToString();
```

but value in not set because patteren is like this

```
Dictionary<key,value>
Dictionary<5,Pakistan>
Dictionary<8,India>
Dictionary<9,Iran>
Dictionary<6,UK>
```

any help or guide if i can set UK in dropdownlist when mystore.country value is 6

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't need to pass `ComboBox` by reference.

To select value of `DataBoud` ComboBox do this:

```
countary_box.SelectedValue = my_store.countary_id; //im not 100% sure that this is the key, so change it to equivalent of item.countary_id
```

And it will preselect give value.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is in this line:

```
countary_box.Text = countary_box.Items.FindByValue(my_store.countary).ToString();
```

In ASP.NET you can set the `SelectedValue` property via the [`Text` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.text.aspx) of a `DropDownList` (like in Winforms). Note the difference, you set the value by the text property.  But `ListItem.ToString` returns the text not the  value property.

So you need this:

```
countary_box.Text = my_store.countary.ToString(); // if countary is the int which is used as key
```

or the same using `SelectedValue` directly:

```
countary_box.SelectedValue = my_store.countary.ToString();
```